# sed too greedy (+ vs *)

Tags: sed, greedy

I have lines like this:

```
scaffold157|size21652:7243-9055/0_1813 10 -2127 86.5772 0 272 854 1813 1 185842 186425 147764049 254
```

I need to remove part from "/" until word boundary (first tab), so in my example this part:

```
/0_1813
```

with this result:

```
scaffold157|size21652:7243-9055 10 -2127 86.5772 0 272 854 1813 1 185842 186425 147764049 254
```

However, my sed seems to be too greedy with

```
 sed 's/\/0_.*\b//'
```

eating all columns. However, with .+, command doesn't work at all and nothing is replaced. What am I doing wrong? Why is .+ not working?

Comment: The only difference between `*` and `+` is that the former allows zero repetitions. Both are greedy. (In addition, it appears that you `sed` dialect does not support `+` at all without syntax extensions.) Stingy repeats are not usually supported by `sed` but in e.g. Perl the stingy variant is `*?` / `+?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `.+` is behaving the way you are seeing is that `+` is only a metacharacter in EREs and sed uses BREs by default so unless you enable EREs by adding `-r` or escaping as `\+` sed considers `+` just a literal plus character.

That's an aside though, all you need is:

```
$ sed 's|/[^[:space:]]*[[:space:]]*||' file
scaffold157|size21652:7243-905510 -2127 86.5772 0 272 854 1813 1 185842 186425 147764049 254
```

You can probably replace `[[:space:]]` with `\s` and `[^[:space:]]` with `\S` in some seds, e.g. GNU.

Answer (score 1):

Match digits instead:

```
sed 's/\/0_[0-9]*//'
```

Or negated spaces:

```
sed 's/\/0_[^ \t]*//'
sed 's/\/0_[^[:blank:]]*//'
sed -r 's/\/0_\S*\b//'
```

Probably with negated spaces, `\b` is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to remove part from "/" until word boundary (first tab)

here this one-liner gives your expected output:

```
sed -r 's#/\S*\b##'
```

Comment: I like this one the best, but what those # and ## mean, please?

Comment: @Perlnika separators, to avoid escaping `/`.